# What does this notation mean? Set of real numbers transposed??

Tags: matrices, notation

In the below:

[image]

from top of Page 13: http://www.ntuzov.com/Nik_Site/Niks_files/Research/papers/stat_arb/Ahmed_2009.pdf

how do you interpret what x is an element of? It looks like the set of real numbers, transposed, power set with p?? :s

Comment: You draw the real number line, and then rotate it by 90 degrees :)

Comment: Seriously.....? It's just a vector of the real numbers? What about the "x p" part?

Comment: I think you'll need to specify what $T$ and $p$ are.

Comment: @JackM T is not defined, I believe it does mean transposed. I will link the paper if you want to see. p stands for a stock price.

Comment: What if $\mathbb R^p$ means column vectors and $\mathbb R^{T \times p}$ means row vectors?

No: $p$ is a real number, a variable, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still think it's a typo, and that there should be an $n$. If you look at other papers/sources on time-varying covariates (for example, [this one](http://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~dzhang2/st745/chap10.pdf)), they say that $\mathbf{x_i}$ is column vector, and since we know $\beta$ is also a column vector, it has to be a dot product (implying T is the transpose operation). I think it's just errors and incorrect notation in the paper you're looking at. Based on what I've seen, it should say something like:

$$
\beta\in\mathbb{R}^p, \quad\mathbb{x_t}\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times n}
$$

otherwise:

- The summations being provided later in your paper do not have enough $\mathbb{x_i}$ vectors
- The dot product between $\mathbb{x_i}$ and $\beta$ is undefined
- If T were a variable, it is never clearly defined

Comment: Oh sorry didn't realise this is what you pointed out in your other answer!!! It wasn't because I didn't trust your judgement :)

Comment: No worries, I had to stop and look at it a bit myself, it's a pretty confusing (and awful) typo, to be honest. :)

Comment: Don't suppose you could glance at this one could you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443022/what-is-this-notation-relating-to-the-jacobian-matrix-operation

you'll know the answer in about 5 seconds! :)