# What is this notation relating to the Jacobian matrix operation?

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, notation

In the below image, in the very bottom-most equation is the partial differential at the end of the equation being multiplied to every element in the inverse Jacobian matrix (and then beta_n added)? Or is this just a notional aspect to show what each Jacobian element is based on?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? I usually find it helpful to write out the expression when $n=2$ or $n=3$ in its full form. (You'll be lucky to find someone that can understand *and coherently explain* such complicated expressions without giving them any context and without giving them a searchable reference.)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your still thinking a little bit too hard, maybe because you're still confused about what NR is actually doing, and what the jacobian does for it. As I mentioned previously, the jacobian matrix J is a function of the beta value for you current iteration (in this case, $\beta_n$).

Much like a function of x is written as $f(x)$, $J(\beta_n)$ is simply saying the numerical Jacobian is a function of your current iteration's beta value. In Eq. 4, your simply taking the inverse of whatever matrix you get.

For each element $J(j,k)$ in $J$, use Eq. 3 to find out what it is.

Comment: Its not the J(βn) I am confused about, its the part following after that: the d/dB of Log L - is this just notation, indicating what is contained within the Jacobian matrix elements?

Comment: That's a vector, where each element is calculated using Eq 2.